# What is different between scipy.sparse.csr_matrix and scipy.sparse.lil_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

What is different between `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` and `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`? These matrices represent sparse matrices, but I don't know what is different.

Additionally, what is each advantage for using `lil_matrix` or `csr_matrix`?

Comment: That a look at [Understanding scipy sparse matrix types](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/understanding-scipy-sparse-matrix-types) after reading [it's official document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

`csr_matrix` is the Compressed Sparse Row matrix, while
`csc_matrix` is the Compressed Sparse Column matrix.

So if you know your data will be large and sparse row-wise, you'll likely want to use `csr_matrix`. If, instead your date is sparse column-wise, you'll want to use a `csc_matrix`.

As explained in this [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/), there are several ways to encode sparse matrices, 2 of them are *csr* and *csc*, which stand for *Compressed Sparse Row* and *Compressed Sparse Column* respectively:

- Compressed Sparse Row. The sparse matrix is represented using three one-dimensional arrays for the non-zero values, the extents of the rows, and the column indexes.
- Compressed Sparse Column. The same as the Compressed Sparse Row method except the column indices are compressed and read first before the row indices.